# Enable/Disable GIF in picturebox onhover

Tags: c#, winforms, gif, onmouseover

[image: MouseHover]

The GIF is default to play when the form load, but i want it to stop the animation when the form load so i add the **pictureBox1.Enabled = false;** but MouseHover or MouseEnter doesn't work to resume the gif to play.

Comment: I am pretty sure mouse events are disabled on controls that have `Enabled = false;` ... this is why the events are not firing.

Comment: Just tested it. When you set `Enabled = false` you won't get any more mouse events.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Answer (score 2):

Save gif and gif as image both in your resource. Then on form load set gif image in picture box, to show gif, load it in picture box in mouse hover event. Also when mouse leave set gif image to picture box as done in code.

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.download__2_; //Gif Image
            }
    
            private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.fa9e27a7534060df383ab54354fcead3; //Actual Gif
            }
    
            private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.download__2_; //Gif Image
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the form's/container's mouemove to check if the picturebox is under the cursor and then activate it.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("enabled");
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!pictureBox1.Enabled)
    {
        pictureBox1.Enabled = (GetChildAtPoint(e.Location) == pictureBox1);
    }
}
```